# Why does Cesium have a higher Boiling point compared to Rb?

Tags: alkali-metals

i know BP should decreese down the group as Cohesive energy decreeses down the group but i found out that cs>Rb in terms of B.P..
so what other factor is affecting this?

Comment: What's the source of your data?